# How to save a button across a configuration change?

Tags: android

In my Activity, I have a field that is a button. It's value is always the currently selected button in a LinearLayout that is created dynamically in the activity. I want this field to always point to the button that is currently selected, however, if I select a button and then change the configuration, the field no longer points to the selected button. What can I do so that I can save this value across a configuration change? 
Here's my code:

Activity.java

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button myButton;
    LinearLayout myLayout;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            LayoutParams rowParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);
            row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                final Button button = new Button(this);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        setMyButton(button);
                    }
                });
            }
            row.addView(button);
        }
        myLayout.addView(row);
    }

    public void setMyButton(Button button) {
        myButton = button;
    }
}
```

I have looked into using some savedInstanceState methods but none of them have one for a Button, only integers and booleans.
What can I do so that I can retain the value of myButton when the configuration changes?

Comment: You could save all buttons in an array when you generate them and then just save the array index (an int) in the bundle.

Comment: Thanks! This works well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onSaveInstanceState()` as long as you have some way to *identify* the button you want to save; you don't have to save the button itself.

Normally, you'd use the button's `id` for this purpose, but since you're dynamically creating the buttons at runtime (instead of putting them in your XML layout) I recommend using the button's `tag` instead.

Save the button's tag in `onSaveInstanceState()`, and then when you're creating the buttons, if you create a button with that same tag, save it as `myButton`.

`onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("myButtonTag", myButton != null ? (String) myButton.getTag() : null);
}
```

At the top of `onCreate()`:

```
    String myButtonTag = null;

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        myButtonTag = savedInstanceState.getString("myButtonTag");
    }
```

Inside your inner `for` loop:

```
            final Button button = new Button(this);
            String tag = i + "," + j;
            button.setTag(tag);

            if (tag.equals(myButtonTag)) {
                myButton = button;
            }
```